# Вывод категорий в результате поиска

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Есть сайт объявлений. На данный момент работаю над SEO. Я хочу чтобы в результате поиска выводились еще и категории (перечеслении) чего-нибудь, то есть так (внизу изображения):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под некоторыми результатами поиска Google отображаются ссылки, которые называются ссылками сайта. Они помогают пользователям быстро переходить к интересующим их веб-страницам. Наши системы анализируют структуру ссылок на сайте, чтобы находить короткие пути, благодаря которым ускоряется процесс поиска нужной информации.

1. Основной результат поиска.
2. Ссылки сайта.

Мы показываем ссылки сайта только в том случае, если они могут оказаться полезными. Если структура ресурса не позволяет нашим алгоритмам выявить разделы, соответствующие запросу, ссылки показаны не будут.

В настоящее время ссылки добавляются автоматически. Соответствующие алгоритмы постоянно совершенствуются, и в дальнейшем мы сможем учитывать пожелания веб-мастеров. Однако есть ряд оптимальных методов, позволяющих уже сейчас улучшить качество таких ссылок. Например, текст внутренних ссылок и их описание в атрибуте alt должны быть информативными, краткими и уникальными.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=ru